# Local notification Xamarin forms .netstandard 2

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, localnotification

I am trying to use local notification in Xamarin forms with .net standard 2.0

I have tried the following link :

[click here](https://github.com/edsnider/LocalNotificationsPlugin)

when I use this function :

```
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("title", "body", 101, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5));
```

And I have this error :

Unhandled Exception:

"Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: md54b33d38a21a950def308c8bb6f6e0d30.ScheduledAlarmHandler
"

I cannot see how to manage it, thanks in advance

If there is a better solution, I will take .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added the nuget to all projects?

Comment: @SunnySonic   yes

Comment: so you're still having the problem? what have you tried? on which platforms do you get this error?

Comment: @SunnySonic on windows

Answer (score 0):

There is little to go on without knowing what you have tried. Personally i prefer this nuget plugin for the same purpose: https://github.com/aritchie/notifications

That is the only one that works with sound for me on all devices.